# Can I leave on the day of expiration of my Vietnam Visa?

Tags: visas, vietnam

My visa in Vietnam expires May 1st, can I buy a plane ticket to fly out of Vietnam on May 1st or do I need to leave the day before expiration? I found one forum entry where a person said a visa is valid until midnight on the day of expiration, meaning it would be okay if I leave Vietnam before midnight on May 1st. Is that true? Or do I have to leave April 30th, before the expiration date?

Answer (score 8):

As it is said in the approval letter and your visa: It will be valid from  1 April 2014 through 1 May 2014. Thus you feel free to stay until the end of 1 May, no need to exit before. Even several hours excess, no problem!

Comment: This then depends on a precise agreed definition of "through" in this sentence structure in English.

Comment: Several hours excess _can_ be a problem if you do it deliberately.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question, and according to http://visavietnam.pro/vi/faq/ you can leave on the same day as your visa expires. I am also going to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Sure. You are allowed to leave Vietnam before or ON visa expiry date.The penalty applies only when you overstay the visa.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is ok. You can leave Vietnam on May 1 which is not problem. However if you leave Vietnam on May 2 you can pay fee 20-50 USD. I may catch this issue.